# OpenSSL EVP Leaking Bytes

Tags: c, memory-leaks, openssl, valgrind, evp-cipher

I'm using [OpenSSL's EVP routine](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) and can not eliminate all still reachable memory. The tutorial linked above leaks this much:

```
==30413== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30413==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30413==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30413==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30413==    still reachable: 2,200 bytes in 27 blocks
==30413==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

and with the addition of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503993/memory-leak-in-openssl-function-evp-encryptfinal-ex), I was able to get it down to:

```
==30437== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30437==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30437==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30437==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30437==    still reachable: 744 bytes in 13 blocks
==30437==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

**Is it possible to eliminate these? Is it something I should even bother with?**

I've seen conflicting answers on SO stating that "still reachable" memory is a memory leak and others saying it isn't, hence my confusion.

Comment: How about putting your function into a big for loop and checking whether the _leaked memory_ size is increasing? If not, then you can be close to sure, that it has to do with OpenSSL initialization. If so, then it's not a problem. Also, don't use deprecated `ERR_remove_state`, use `ERR_remove_thread_state` instead.

Comment: How would I go about putting a for loop in my program that doesn't affect EVP? The entire program is solely the EVP routine. Changing `ERR_remove_state` to `ERR_remove_thread_state` made no difference in bytes still reachable. Added a for loop of the entire program, heap usage increased as expected, but still reachable bytes remained the same.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Forgot to include your name in the last comment. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about using these suggestions? https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG13

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Just tried all of those but they made no difference (I'm already using most anyways). Still stuck at `still reachable: 744 bytes in 13 blocks`.